# Can Android wearable send event to the phone and call 3rd party Services?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm new to wearable development, it's quite standard that wearable only uses GoogleAPIs. But is it possible to call a background service from the phone and send the results back ?

this is my thoughts:

1. Wearable send an event to the phone via MessageAPI, eg: request a particular news feed.
2. The phone wakes up it's service when it receives the event.
3. services does the background task and post the results back to wearable.

I haven't try this approach yet, just want to gather more opinions first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a completely valid approach. I understand, that you are sending the data to the phone, because you need some resource (most likely internet connection) that is not available to you on the wearable?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct and I don't want the phone to launch any activities as well.

Comment: That's perfectly valid. You don't need to have any activity/UI on the phone, just a service that performs request on behalf of the wearable app. It's a proxy.